# Boost.Python dll being skipped on compile

Tags: c++, python, visual-studio-2010, boost, boost-python

I am new to python programming and am looking to incorporate some C++ dll's into python. I found boost.python to be the most common answer to this issue and have been trying to test it with a simple 'hello world' application that comes with the boost.python package. Following the tutorial at `http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/hello.html`

I am running Windows 7 using Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0.

My python directory is `'C:\Python27'`, Boost is `'C:\Boost\boost_1_54_0'`

I have set the user-config.jam file to `using msvc : 10.0 ;` and `using python : 2.7 : C:\\Python27 ;`

When I invoke bjam I get the following..

```
...failed msvc.link.dll C:\Boost\boost_1_54_0\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\debug\boost_python-vc100-gd-1_54.dll C:\Boost\boost_1_54_0\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\debug\boost_python-vc100-gd-1_54.lib C:\Boost\boost_1_54_0\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\debug\boost_python-vc100-gd-1_54.pdb...
...removing C:\Boost\boost_1_54_0\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\debug\boost_python-vc100-gd-1_54.lib
...removing C:\Boost\boost_1_54_0\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\debug\boost_python-vc100-gd-1_54.pdb
...skipped <pbin\msvc-10.0\debug>hello_ext.pyd for lack of <pC:\Boost\boost_1_54_0\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\debug>boost_python-vc100-gd-1_54.lib...
...skipped <pbin\msvc-10.0\debug>hello_ext.lib for lack of <pC:\Boost\boost_1_54_0\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\debug>boost_python-vc100-gd-1_54.lib...
...skipped <pbin\msvc-10.0\debug>hello_ext.pdb for lack of <pC:\Boost\boost_1_54_0\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\debug>boost_python-vc100-gd-1_54.lib...
...skipped <p.>boost_python-vc100-gd-1_54.dll for lack of <pC:\Boost\boost_1_54_0\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\debug>boost_python-vc100-gd-1_54.dll...
...skipped <p.>hello_ext.pyd for lack of <pbin\msvc-10.0\debug>hello_ext.pyd...
...skipped <pbin\hello.test\msvc-10.0\debug>hello for lack of <pbin\msvc-10.0\debug>hello_ext.pyd...
...failed updating 3 targets...
...skipped 7 targets...
```

All that is created is an .obj file in:

`C:\Boost\boost_1_54_0\libs\python\example\tutorial\bin\msvc-10.0\debug`

From my basic limited knowledge it appears the files that are relied upon are being removed just before compilation. I have searched long and hard for a solution but to no avail. It feels like I am missing something very elementary.

Thank you.

EDIT: Updating to python 3.3 seems to have gotten me closer. It is no longer removing the two files from bin.v2, but it is still not compiling a .dll or .pyb file.

```
PS C:\Boost\boost_1_54_0\libs\python\example\tutorial> .\bjam
...patience...
...patience...
...found 1681 targets...
...updating 7 targets...
msvc.link.dll bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pyd
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_54.lib'

    call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 >nul
link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /MANIFEST /subsystem:console/out:"bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pyd" 
/IMPLIB:"bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Python33\libs"   @"bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pyd.rsp"
    if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%

...failed msvc.link.dll bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pyd bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.lib bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pdb bin\msvc-10.0\debug\hello_ext.pdb...
...skipped <p.>hello_ext.pyd for lack of <pbin\msvc-10.0\debug>hello_ext.pyd...
...failed updating 3 targets...
...skipped 1 target...
```

Comment: SOLVED: First I rebuilt boost.python by running `b2 toolset=msvc-10.0 --with-python --user-config=user-config.jam --build-type=complete stage` in `C:\Boost\boost_1_54_0` then I copied the `boost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_54.lib` file into the tutorial folder. Not sure this is the best solution but it seems to now be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: First I rebuilt boost.python by running `b2 toolset=msvc-10.0 --with-python --user-config=user-config.jam --build-type=complete stage` in `C:\Boost\boost_1_54_0` then I copied the `boost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_54.lib` file into the tutorial folder. Not sure this is the best solution but it seems to now be working.

Comment: Are you adding the `C:\Boost\boost_1_54_0` folder as an include directory for the linker to find `boost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_54.lib`? When I compile a boost.python app on windows, I don't need to move boost_python*.lib to my local directory.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to mention python installation path in your configuration file:

```
using python : 2.7 : C:\Python27\;
```

Did you cd into the same directory where jamroot and hello.cpp is located?

Comment: Sorry, I had done that as well in the user-config, and yes I am the same directory as jamroot and hello.cpp. 

Within the 'bin' folder it creates a 'hello.test' folder containing nothing and 'msvc-10.0' folder containing 'hello.obj', 'hello.obj.rsp' and 'hello_ext.pyd.rsp'

Comment: It seems to not like the 'toolset<msvc>' at the end, but I can add that argument when invoking bjam no? Otherwise I am still getting ...failed updating 3 targets... and ...skipped 1 target...
Thank you

Comment: @gargavin sorry about the typo, and shame that it doesn't work. I hope that you get a good answer. I'll remove the comment to reduce the noise since it does not help.